# How do i connect 3 Node

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

am new to using Neo4j can someone explain how i can do this. i have a csv file that contains 3 column which looks like these

```
offences|  places | recorded
rape    |  nicosia| 1
robbery |  nicosia| 3
rape    |  limasol| 4
robbery |  limasol| 5
```

what i want is a way to connect an offence with a place and the recorded number here is what i came up with.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///crime2.csv' AS Line 
MERGE (district:DISTRICT { Name: Line[1]})
CREATE (crime:CRIME { Name: Line[0]})
CREATE (number:Number{ Name:toInteger(Line[2])})
CREATE (number)-[:Amount]->(crime)-[:From]->(district)
WITH district, crime, number
MATCH (a:CRIME)-[:`From`]->(b:DISTRICT) RETURN a,b;
```

my code did not handle the job completely instead it display like this
[my code only display the places and the offence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb959.png)

i need a way to show the place -> offences -> recorded_number. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more node match condition in your query

```
MATCH (n:Number)-[:Amount]->(a:CRIME)-[:From]->(b:DISTRICT) RETURN a,b,n;
```

If you are using this in any real-life use case/project, then You need to think about the data model you are using (as suggested by @Tomaz).

**EDIT:**

I tried above query on my laptop and it's giving me expected output.

I suggest you separate the data load query and return query because each time you run this query you are duplicating half of the data.

You have used create clause which is creating Crime and Number nodes again each time you are running this query.

Delete existing data:

```
MATCH (n:Number),(a:CRIME),(b:DISTRICT) DETACH DELETE  a,b,n;
```

Load Data

```
LOAD CSV FROM {path} AS Line  
MERGE (district:DISTRICT { Name: Line[1]}) 
CREATE (crime:CRIME { Name: Line[0]}) 
CREATE (number:Number{Name:toInteger(Line[2])}) 
CREATE(number)-[:Amount]->(crime)-[:From]->(district);
```

Get the result:

```
MATCH (n:Number)-[:Amount]->(a:CRIME)-[:From]->(b:DISTRICT) RETURN a,b,n;
```

[image]

Comment: after adding one more match the relationship is not showing in the graph.. how do i fix it .. like i want it to show like the image i posted on my question

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply add number to the `MATCH` query

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///crime2.csv' AS Line 
MERGE (district:DISTRICT { Name: Line[1]})
CREATE (crime:CRIME { Name: Line[0]})
CREATE (number:Number{ Name:toInteger(Line[2])})
CREATE (number)-[:Amount]->(crime)-[:From]->(district)
WITH district, crime, number
MATCH p = (:Number)-[:AMOUNT]->(:CRIME)-[:`From`]->(:DISTRICT) RETURN p;
```

There might be a problem with your modeling though. I wouldn't create a number as a separate node, but I would store the amount in the property of relationship between district and crime or something else. The way you do it right now doesnt make sense.

Another thing to add is you probably want to change

`CREATE (crime:CRIME { Name: Line[0]})`

to

`MERGE (crime:CRIME { Name: Line[0]})`

so that there is one node for a specific crime as this is graph database and you want to have your data connected IMO.

Comment: How can we identify which number is for particular any District?